# backbone.js modelbinding with deeply nested objects

Tags: backbone.js

I'm using the backbone.js plugin "Modelbinding", which is an excellent approach to knockout-style model-to-dom binding. It's pretty great so far.

My question is, my object has some deeply nested branches that I want to bind UI elements to, and modelbinding seems to just use a simple `Backbone.Model.get()` to pull out the data, so can only take a flat, top-level field name. But my thing needs to be asked for `model.get('submodel').get('fieldName')`.

I'm representing assets that are leased. In some cases I want to show the leasing company's name, which is in the main Asset models' "lease" field's object's "lessor" field's object's "companyName" field. In javascript that's just Asset.lease.lessor.companyName, plain and simple. But I can't find any way to Backbone that.

I went into backbone.js and hacked the get method to go from `this.attributes[attr]` to `eval('this.attributes.' + attr);`, which I thought sure would get me what I was after, but it broke things in ways I didn't really understand.

Comment: You really shouldn't hack *anything* into using eval. ;) Can you show the nested data and the backbone code that deals with it?

Comment: Not to throw you off with another lib, but [Batman.js](https://github.com/Shopify/batman) has deep paths built in. As for Backbone.js, others have tried to offer deep object models. See [`Backbone.DeepModel`](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-deep-model) for instance.

Comment: It looks like the Backbone.DeepModel plugin in combination with my Backbone.ModelBinding plugin should solve this problem. Thanks for the link, Crescent Fresh!

Comment: @Tomalak - I know, it was more proof of concept. I wouldn't put that in production.

Comment: @CrescentFresh - Brilliant!!! Backbone.DeepModel is exactly what I was looking for. Post that as the answer so I can accept it please. I did consider Batman, but it's in CoffeeScript and if I throw one more new language (or even idiom like CS is) at my manager he'll lose his mind.

Comment: @Dan Ray: meh, I can't vouch for DeepModel (never used it). That's why I offered it as a comment rather than an answer.